# For Each Loop Editing Original 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

In the for each loop, the output is 6. However, I thought that the output would be 0 since, at least for one dimensional arrays, for each loops only traverse arrays. How is "g" being edited if "f" is only a local variable in the loop?

```
int[][] g = new int[7][7];

for(int[] f : g) {
    for(int h = 0; h < f.length; h++)
        f[h] = 6;
}

System.out.println(g[4][6]);
```

Comment: An `int[]` is a reference type, so your `int[][]` has elements that are of reference type. Thus you can modify the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though Java is [pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1079354), if the values you pass are references to mutable data types, they can be mutated.

As you know, `f` is the value that you're iterating over in an enhanced-for loop, but it represents each element contained inside of your two-dimensional array `g`.

In this scenario, it's your `int[]` that is mutable.  You are actively editing the values in your two-dimensional array to another value entirely.